# Iam working on Springboot and iam getting page display error

Tags: java, spring-boot

Iam trying to develop a sample springboot application.While i managed to get my setup complete.Iam getting following error.
I did't get any error while running the code but iam getting page display error as 404 .....and here is my code.I get the above error on starup, Any quick help?

Application.java

```
package com.access6.springbootcrudapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootcrudapiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootcrudapiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.access6.springcrudapiEntity;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_employee")
public class Employee {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String gender;
    @Column
    private String department;
    @Column
    private Date dob;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", department=" + department + ", dob="
                + dob + "]";
    }
    public Employee get(int id2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }




}
```

controller.java

```
package com.access6.springcrudapiController;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.access6.springcrudapiEntity.Employee;
import com.access6.springcrudapiService.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {


    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/employee")
    public List<Employee> get(){
        return employeeService.get();

    }

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public Employee save(@RequestBody Employee employeeobj){
        employeeService.save(employeeobj);
        return employeeobj;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public Employee get(@PathVariable int id){
        Employee employeeobj= employeeService.get(id);
        if (employeeobj== null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Employee with id"+id+"is not found");

        }
        return employeeobj;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable int id){
         employeeService.delete(id);
        return "Employee has been deleted with id:"+id;

    }
    @PutMapping("/employee")
    public Employee Update(@RequestBody Employee employeeobj){
        employeeService.Update(employeeobj);
        return employeeobj;
    }
    }
```

console

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-04-14 18:54:06.029  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.s.SpringbootcrudapiApplication       : Starting SpringbootcrudapiApplication on DESKTOP-10R8SDT with PID 9964 (C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\springbootcrudapi\target\classes started by admin in C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\springbootcrudapi)
2020-04-14 18:54:06.033  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.s.SpringbootcrudapiApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-14 18:54:06.158  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2020-04-14 18:54:06.158  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-04-14 18:54:06.159  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-04-14 18:54:07.367  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-14 18:54:07.409  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 20ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-14 18:54:08.126  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$847b199] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-04-14 18:54:08.296  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2020-04-14 18:54:09.078  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-14 18:54:09.113  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-14 18:54:09.113  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-04-14 18:54:09.294  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-14 18:54:09.294  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3131 ms
2020-04-14 18:54:09.595  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-14 18:54:10.528  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-14 18:54:10.620  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-04-14 18:54:10.784  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-04-14 18:54:11.561  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-04-14 18:54:11.701  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2020-04-14 18:54:11.905  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-04-14 18:54:11.914  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-14 18:54:12.023  WARN 9964 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-04-14 18:54:12.339  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-14 18:54:15.462  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-04-14 18:54:17.964  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-14 18:54:17.970  INFO 9964 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.s.SpringbootcrudapiApplication       : Started SpringbootcrudapiApplication in 12.694 seconds (JVM running for 14.095)
2020-04-14 18:56:37.970  INFO 9964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-14 18:56:37.970  INFO 9964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-14 18:56:37.987  INFO 9964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 17 ms
```

error page

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Apr 14 18:59:53 GMT-08:00 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: By making which http request do you get the error page? Which is the url that you're trying to access?

Comment: You haven't shown/added JSP or Thymeleaf template.